# webrtc remote video not playing in phonegap ios app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webrtc, phonegap

I have found quite a few similar qustions but they are mainly old and outdated and some of them provided a few pointers which I followed to no avail.

Basically, I'm tring to use `webrtc` and the `phonegap iosrtc` plugin to create a simple 2 way video chat.

I followed everything to the letter and I managed to show my own video in the app but the 'remote' video is not showing and I ant figure out what the issue is at all!

I have enabled the debugging in phonegap but I don't get any errors.

This is my complete code:

**HTML:**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  


<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dist/RTCMultiConnection.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/node_modules/webrtc-adapter/out/adapter.js"></script>
<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>


<!-- custom layout for HTML5 audio/video elements -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dev/getHTMLMediaElement.css">
<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dev/getHTMLMediaElement.js"></script>

<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/node_modules/recordrtc/RecordRTC.js"></script>

<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="ios-websocket-hack.js"></script>
  <section class="make-center">
    <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="record-entire-conference"> Record Entire Conference In The Browser?</label>
      <span id="recording-status" style="display: none;"></span>
      <button id="btn-stop-recording" style="display: none;">Stop Recording</button>
      <br><br>

      <input type="text" id="room-id" value="abcdef" autocorrect=off autocapitalize=off size=20>
      <button id="open-room">Open Room</button>
      <button id="join-room">Join Room</button>
      <button id="open-or-join-room">Auto Open Or Join Room</button>

    </div>

    <div id="videos-container" style="margin: 20px 0;"></div>

    <div id="room-urls" style="text-align: center;display: none;background: #F1EDED;margin: 15px -10px;border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 189);border-left: 0;border-right: 0;"></div>
  </section>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
// ......................................................
// .......................UI Code........................
// ......................................................
document.getElementById('open-room').onclick = function() {
    disableInputButtons();
    connection.open(document.getElementById('room-id').value, function(isRoomOpened, roomid, error) {
        if(isRoomOpened === true) {
          showRoomURL(connection.sessionid);
        }
        else {
          disableInputButtons(true);
          if(error === 'Room not available') {
            alert('Someone already created this room. Please either join or create a separate room.');
            return;
          }
          alert(error);
        }
    });
};
document.getElementById('join-room').onclick = function() {
    disableInputButtons();
    connection.join(document.getElementById('room-id').value, function(isJoinedRoom, roomid, error) {
      if (error) {
            disableInputButtons(true);
            if(error === 'Room not available') {
              alert('This room does not exist. Please either create it or wait for moderator to enter in the room.');
              return;
            }
            alert(error);
        }
    });
};
document.getElementById('open-or-join-room').onclick = function() {
    disableInputButtons();
    connection.openOrJoin(document.getElementById('room-id').value, function(isRoomExist, roomid, error) {
        if(error) {
          disableInputButtons(true);
          alert(error);
        }
        else if (connection.isInitiator === true) {
            // if room doesn't exist, it means that current user will create the room
            showRoomURL(roomid);
        }
    });
};
// ......................................................
// ..................RTCMultiConnection Code.............
// ......................................................
var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();
// by default, socket.io server is assumed to be deployed on your own URL
//connection.socketURL = '/';
// comment-out below line if you do not have your own socket.io server
connection.socketURL = 'https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/';
connection.socketMessageEvent = 'video-conference-demo';
connection.session = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
};
connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
    OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
    OfferToReceiveVideo: true
};
connection.videosContainer = document.getElementById('videos-container');




connection.onstream = function(event) {
    var existing = document.getElementById(event.streamid);
    if(existing && existing.parentNode) {
      existing.parentNode.removeChild(existing);
    }
    /*event.mediaElement.removeAttribute('src');
    event.mediaElement.removeAttribute('srcObject');
    event.mediaElement.muted = true;
    event.mediaElement.volume = 0;*/
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    try {
        video.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute('autoplay'));
        video.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute('playsinline'));
    } catch (e) {
        video.setAttribute('autoplay', true);
        video.setAttribute('playsinline', true);

    }
    if(event.type === 'local') {

    video.setAttribute('class', 'myvideo');
    //$('.yourVideo').attr('src', event.stream);
    //$('.yourVideo').attr('id', event.streamid);

    alert('local');
      video.volume = 0;
      try {
          video.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute('muted'));
      } catch (e) {
          video.setAttribute('muted', true);

      }
    }


    if (event.type === 'remote') {
    alert('remote');

        video.setAttribute('class', 'othersvideo');
    }


    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
    //var width = parseInt(connection.videosContainer.clientWidth / 3) - 20;
    var width = $(document).width();
    var height = $(document).height();
    var mediaElement = getHTMLMediaElement(video, {
        /*title: event.userid,*/
        buttons: ['full-screen'],
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        showOnMouseEnter: false
    });
    connection.videosContainer.appendChild(mediaElement);


    setTimeout(function() {
    // mediaElement.media.play();          
    video.play();   
    }, 5000);


    mediaElement.id = event.streamid;
    // to keep room-id in cache
    localStorage.setItem(connection.socketMessageEvent, connection.sessionid);
    chkRecordConference.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    if(chkRecordConference.checked === true) {
      btnStopRecording.style.display = 'inline-block';
      recordingStatus.style.display = 'inline-block';
      var recorder = connection.recorder;
      if(!recorder) {
        recorder = RecordRTC([event.stream], {
          type: 'video'
        });
        recorder.startRecording();
        connection.recorder = recorder;
      }
      else {
        recorder.getInternalRecorder().addStreams([event.stream]);
      }
      if(!connection.recorder.streams) {
        connection.recorder.streams = [];
      }
      connection.recorder.streams.push(event.stream);
      recordingStatus.innerHTML = 'Recording ' + connection.recorder.streams.length + ' streams';
    }
    if(event.type === 'local') {
      connection.socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        if(!connection.getAllParticipants().length) {
          location.reload();
        }
      });
    }
};
var recordingStatus = document.getElementById('recording-status');
var chkRecordConference = document.getElementById('record-entire-conference');
var btnStopRecording = document.getElementById('btn-stop-recording');
btnStopRecording.onclick = function() {
  var recorder = connection.recorder;
  if(!recorder) return alert('No recorder found.');
  recorder.stopRecording(function() {
    var blob = recorder.getBlob();
    invokeSaveAsDialog(blob);
    connection.recorder = null;
    btnStopRecording.style.display = 'none';
    recordingStatus.style.display = 'none';
    chkRecordConference.parentNode.style.display = 'inline-block';
  });
};
connection.onstreamended = function(event) {
    var mediaElement = document.getElementById(event.streamid);
    if (mediaElement) {
        mediaElement.parentNode.removeChild(mediaElement);
    }
};
connection.onMediaError = function(e) {
    if (e.message === 'Concurrent mic process limit.') {
        if (DetectRTC.audioInputDevices.length <= 1) {
            alert('Please select external microphone. Check github issue number 483.');
            return;
        }
        var secondaryMic = DetectRTC.audioInputDevices[1].deviceId;
        connection.mediaConstraints.audio = {
            deviceId: secondaryMic
        };
        connection.join(connection.sessionid);
    }
};
// ..................................
// ALL below scripts are redundant!!!
// ..................................
function disableInputButtons(enable) {
    document.getElementById('room-id').onkeyup();
    document.getElementById('open-or-join-room').disabled = !enable;
    document.getElementById('open-room').disabled = !enable;
    document.getElementById('join-room').disabled = !enable;
    document.getElementById('room-id').disabled = !enable;
}
// ......................................................
// ......................Handling Room-ID................
// ......................................................
function showRoomURL(roomid) {
    var roomHashURL = '#' + roomid;
    var roomQueryStringURL = '?roomid=' + roomid;
    var html = '<h2>Unique URL for your room:</h2><br>';
    html += 'Hash URL: <a href="' + roomHashURL + '" target="_blank">' + roomHashURL + '</a>';
    html += '<br>';
    html += 'QueryString URL: <a href="' + roomQueryStringURL + '" target="_blank">' + roomQueryStringURL + '</a>';
    var roomURLsDiv = document.getElementById('room-urls');
    roomURLsDiv.innerHTML = html;
    roomURLsDiv.style.display = 'block';
}
(function() {
    var params = {},
        r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g;
    function d(s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
    var match, search = window.location.search;
    while (match = r.exec(search.substring(1)))
        params[d(match[1])] = d(match[2]);
    window.params = params;
})();
var roomid = '';
if (localStorage.getItem(connection.socketMessageEvent)) {
    roomid = localStorage.getItem(connection.socketMessageEvent);
} else {
    roomid = connection.token();
}
var txtRoomId = document.getElementById('room-id');
txtRoomId.value = roomid;
txtRoomId.onkeyup = txtRoomId.oninput = txtRoomId.onpaste = function() {
    localStorage.setItem(connection.socketMessageEvent, document.getElementById('room-id').value);
};
var hashString = location.hash.replace('#', '');
if (hashString.length && hashString.indexOf('comment-') == 0) {
    hashString = '';
}
var roomid = params.roomid;
if (!roomid && hashString.length) {
    roomid = hashString;
}
if (roomid && roomid.length) {
    document.getElementById('room-id').value = roomid;
    localStorage.setItem(connection.socketMessageEvent, roomid);
    // auto-join-room
    (function reCheckRoomPresence() {
        connection.checkPresence(roomid, function(isRoomExist) {
            if (isRoomExist) {
                connection.join(roomid);
                return;
            }
            setTimeout(reCheckRoomPresence, 5000);
        });
    })();
    disableInputButtons();
}
// detect 2G
if(navigator.connection &&
   navigator.connection.type === 'cellular' &&
   navigator.connection.downlinkMax <= 0.115) {
  alert('2G is not supported. Please use a better internet service.');
}

  window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(" https://vps267717.ovh.net/webrtc", "_blank", "location=no,toolbar=yes");
```

As you can see in my code, I have this:

```
if (event.type === 'remote') {
alert('remote');

    video.setAttribute('class', 'othersvideo');
}
```

But this never fires for some reason!

I have spent the last 3 days trying to figure this out but I haven't had any luck.

So any help and advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jib during my research, I came across your answers a lot which indicates that you know your stuff about webrtc. can you please take a look at my code and see if you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you ever resolve this ?

Comment: @G-Man, NO NEVER... Spent a whole week trying and no one ever replied to me! i assume you have the same issue?

Comment: @jib I ultimately resolved it by disabling the adapter.js stuff.. but most importantly, I decided to stop using this library. Use the library to learn how to do things, but if you are going to build a product, cook your own. This library is full of document references, which makes it hard to use in things like React Native for example. Once you understand webrtc, you can easily reproduce what he has done, without a lot of stuff that you do not need. Good luck

Comment: @JamesJuanjie Did you resolve this? I got same issue remote video not showing